# mac osx 10.8 ssh works but git says could not resolve hostname

Tags: macos, git, networking, ssh

I'm trying to clone a remote git repo through ssh. When I try ssh into the remote host it prompts for password and works:

```
$ ssh gerry@5.12.221.37
```

However when I tried cloning the repository it gives this error

```
$ git clone ssh://gerry@5.12.221.37:/home/gerry/gitrepos/Test.git
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 5.12.221.37:: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

There isn't any network issue since I can even perform telnet to 5.12.221.37 port 22.

I'm using mac osx 10.8, does anyone know how I can troubleshoot / resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have keys set up or are you using password authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the colon:

`git clone ssh://gerry@5.12.221.37/home/gerry/gitrepos/Test.git`

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. The official git book must have misled me because they put the colon there (http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

The clone works fine with
    git clone ssh://gerry@5.12.221.37/home/gerry/gitrepos/Test.git